# Customising Dojo DateTextBox - want mm/yy input only

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, calendar

I'm having a little difficulty programming the DateTextBox widget to operate with a month and year only input, and to put a mm/yy format in the DateTextBox. Can anyone help me tidy this up?

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/resources/dojo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>

<body class="claro">

  <div id="dt_text" data-dojo-type="dojox/form/DateTextBox" data-dojo-props="popupClass: 'dojox/widget/MonthAndYearlyCalendar'">
  </div>
```

This [DateTextBox JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vogomatix/k6yzP/3/) shows my weak efforts so far. Alternative methods of getting a mm/yy textbox input without using these widgets are equally welcome.

Just to clarify, if you're going an alternative route, the important bit is a good mm/yy popup which I can use to inject the selected date into the textbox. I'm familiar with different types of text box djits, but not with date selector popups.

I'm using Dojo 1.8 and cannot upgrade so please make your answers compatible with this version

Comment: Are you prefer there is a UI for selection or text key-in???

Comment: I want a text key in with optional mm/yy date picker as the datetextbox provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have prepared two modules with [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glJKZ.png) to you which they both match your requirement.

- Quickly changing year
- Easy to select month and year
- skip to select day

Modules:

1. `DateTextBox` with MonthAndYearlyCalendar View
2. `MonthTextBox`

```or-tag-here
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/dojo/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/dojo/dojox/widget/Calendar/Calendar.css">

    <script>
        dojo.require("dojox.widget.MonthAndYearlyCalendar");
    </script>

    <body class="claro">
        <input type="text" name="monthNyear" value="11/2013" data-dojo-type="dojox/form/DateTextBox" data-dojo-props="constraints:{datePattern: 'MM/yyyy'}, popupClass:'dojox.widget.MonthAndYearlyCalendar'" />
        <input type="text" name="monthOnly" value="11" data-dojo-type="dojox/form/MonthTextBox" />
    </body>
```

Comment: Thankyou - the first example is exactly what I was trying to achieve. From your example I found the problem with my version, which was that I was not requiring the correct Dojo Module.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest use ValidationTextbox, it is more earlier to use and meet your requirement too.
Here is the [reference link](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/ValidationTextBox.html#dijit-form-validationtextbox) and sample code you could copy and paste(tested in 1.8.3)

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/resources/dojo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>

<body class="claro">
  <input type="text" name="monthNyear" id="monthNyear" value="12/99" required="true" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="regExp:'\\d{2}\/\\d{2}', invalidMessage:'Invalid mm/yy'" />
```

Comment: Validation textbox doesn't have a date picker. I do want a date picker widget attached to the box, that allows picking the month and year.

Comment: You replied me that prefer key-in, instead of UI selection. Anyway, check my latest answer.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/resources/dojo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>

<body class="claro">
  <input type="text" name="skippedDay" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" data-dojo-props="constraints:{datePattern:'yyyy-MM'}" value="2013-12" />
```

PS: you can change the `yyyy-MM` to `MM-yyyy` to match your format.
But I tried that, the default value will be ignore. (in version 1.8.3).

PS2: users still needed select the day in popup calendar, but the textbox will not show and submit the day.

Comment: Yes, however the complaint is that the particular month and year may be a long time in the past. Having a popup is liked but it needs to be able to select months and years quickly. The dojox.widget.calendar seems to offer what I need if only I can integrate it into the DateTextBox, or get it working as some sort of popup which injects data into a ValidationTextBox.