# Removing Date Selection from dijit/form/DateTextBox

Tags: datepicker, dojo, dijit.form, dijit.layout

I am using dijit/form/DateTextBox. Is it possible to select only Month and Year ?

Thanks

Comment: See this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638682/customising-dojo-datetextbox-want-mm-yy-input-only

Comment: User has to still select the date in the datetextbox though the value in the text box will be populated without date.
Can it be possible to populate the value on the selection of month only ?